# spring retryable with different interceptors

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

Suppose a rather simple case. I have a `@Service`:

```
@Service
public class Dummy {

    @Retryable(interceptor = "myInterceptor")
    public Response getResponse() {
       // whatever
    }

}
```

Now depending on a `@Conditional`, I want to either enable or disable the `@Retryable`. Currently, I have a (dirty?) hack in place for this:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMyPropertyEnabled
public RetryOperationsInterceptor myInterceptor() {
    return // an instance of an interceptor that actually retries
}

@Bean("myInterceptor")
@ConditionalOnMyPropertyDisabled
public RetryOperationsInterceptor myNeverRetryInterceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless().retryPolicy(new NeverRetryPolicy()).build();
}
```

So when my condition is met, get a real retryable instance. When it is not, get me a `NeverRetryPolicy` retryable.

The problem that bothers me, is that I can't write a proper test to assert the presence of a certain bean in my context based on those `@ConditionalOnMyPropertyEnabled` and `@ConditionalOnMyPropertyDisabled`.

This is because the bean name is `myInterceptor` in both cases, which is an artifact of the fact that `@Retryable` takes a single `interceptor` as input; not an array for example.

---

In theory I could create something like this:

```
class MetadataAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor extends RetryOperationsInterceptor {

    private final RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor;

    MetadataAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor(RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor) {
        this.interceptor = interceptor;
    }

    private Map<String, String> metadata = Collections.emptyMap();

    Map<String, String> getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    void setMetadata(Map<String, String> metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }
}
```

And use `MetadataAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor` with a different metadata for each of my instances and test against that, but this looks like a big over kill; especially when you think that I need this for a test only.

May be there is a simpler way that I miss?